Drawing a line each month in pinescrypt indicator
Can someone help me? Its just a few lines of code.
I need an indicator that draws 2 lines each month, green and red. Green is Highest high for previous 3 months red is lowest low for previous 3 months. therefore a value of highest high and lowest low for previous 3 months is refreshed every month and the line is horizontal until a new month

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
